# Gridiview em asp.net montagem

Tags: c#, asp.net, framework

Boa tarde Pessoal.
Estou com uma duvida na hora de montar um gridview não possuo muitos conhecimentos em c# eu fiz dessa maneira

```
 string sql = "SELECT pr.codigo_chave,pr.codigo_produto,pr.nome_produto,ca.nome_categoria FROM infobook_net.produtos pr inner join categorias ca on pr.codigo_categoria = ca.codigo_categoria";
    Response.Write(sql);

    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
    try
    {
        sqlConnection1.Open();
        MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = reader;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("não foram encontrados dados");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(Convert.ToString(ex));
    }
```

Ele esta rodando e preenchendo o gridview somente quando tem mais de uma linha de retorno quando so tem uma ele não monta nada e não mostra nada alguem tem uma ideia de como fazer?

obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não precisa iterar sobre o `DataReader` para fazer o `DataBind.` Basta definir o `DataSource` e chamar o método `DataBind` conforme abaixo:

```
String sql = "SELECT pr.codigo_chave,pr.codigo_produto,pr.nome_produto,ca.nome_categoria FROM infobook_net.produtos pr inner join categorias ca on pr.codigo_categoria = ca.codigo_categoria";
Response.Write(sql);

cmd.CommandText = sql;
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
Try
{
    sqlConnection1.Open();
    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    If (reader.HasRows)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = reader;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    Else
    {
        Response.Write("não foram encontrados dados");
    }
}
Catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(Convert.ToString(ex));
}
```

Comment: Obrigado Richard deu certo Obrigado